# Import object in Odi 12c using ODI SDK

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I' m trying to automate the import of mappings (XML) in ODI 12c, using a Groovy script and the ODI SDK. But my code just keeps running without any result. Here's is my code.

```
txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)
ImportServiceImpl importSrv = new ImportServiceImpl(odiInstance);
importSrv.importObjectFromXml(importSrv.IMPORT_MODE_SYNONYM_INSERT, filename, parentObj, true, null, true);
tm.commit(txnStatus)
```

The code runs for indefinite amount of time until I manually terminate the program. I don't understand what is the problem.
Link to javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/impexp/IImportService.html#importObjectFromXml(int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20char[],%20boolean)

And also, I don't understand the fourth parameter in the method

```
void importObjectFromXml(int pImportMode,
                   java.lang.String pFileName,
                   IImportRoot pObjectParent,
                   boolean pDeclareMissingRepository,
                   char[] pExportKey,
                   boolean pImportWithoutCipherData)
                     throws OdiImportNotSupportedException,
                            OdiImportException,
                            java.io.IOException
```

I tried using both true and false for pDeclareMissingRepository  but none works. Please help, if I'm missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it part of your code or the entire Groovy script? Check you don't miss any import and that you correctly declare `odiInstance`. Also what's the value of parentObj?

Comment: Yes, it is part of my code. The script does give any error while running. There are no unresolved class. The value of parentObj is folder inside project.

Comment: For the first parameter, I see a reference to importSrv and then a space before IMPORT_MODE_SYNONYM_INSERT. Shouldn't it be the interface instead of the instance of the object (and I believe there is a typo, it should be importSrc), and no space? `IImportService.IMPORT_MODE_SYNONYM_INSERT`. Also there is a . at the end of that line, is it normal?

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I have edited the code. I think, using IImportService.IMPORT_MODE_SYNONYM_INSERT or object instance should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `importObjectFromXml` instead of `importFromXml` which is specific to [SmartImport](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/impexp/smartie/impl/SmartImportServiceImpl.html#importFromXml-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-char:A-boolean-).

Try with 
`importSrv.importObjectFromXml(IImportService.IMPORT_MODE_SYNONYM_INSERT, filename, parentObj, true, null, true)`

The pDeclareMissingRepository is linked to the way objects were identified in 11g, with an internal ID and a repository ID. When importing it would check if it could recognize the repository ID from where the object is exported. I don't think it's used anymore but for your usage you can safely leave the value to true.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. The method i used is importObjectFromXml. importFromXml is a typo. I have edited it.

Comment: What about `importers` instead of `importSrv` ? Is it also a typo or is it from your actual code? Could you just paste the code? I feel I'm kinda wasting my time fixing typos ;).