# ODI 12c export and import objects using Java SDK

Tags: java, import, sdk, export, oracle-data-integrator

Hi I am trying to write a pure Java code that can run outside of odi studio to export and import specific objects like mapping variables procedures separately in to xml files.

Any help or code references will be appreciated?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the ODI SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/index.html) provides ways to [export](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/impexp/support/ExportServiceImpl.html) and [import](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/impexp/support/ImportServiceImpl.html) objects.

To export specific objects, have a look at the `exportToXml` and `exportToXmlWithParents` methods.

But first you need to retrieve the objects you want to export, use the "Finder" interfaces for each object type.
For instance for finding mappings, use the [IMappingFinder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/finder/IMappingFinder.html) interface. The `findByName` methods let you find a specific mapping by it's name. The `findByProject` methods let you find all the mappings from a project or a folder.

I'm sure there are some examples online ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I found one similar thread but dont see any conenction made to reposotory. i guess this runs nativlely inside odi studio.  Not sure how to establish odiInstance. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225923/import-object-in-odi-12c-using-odi-sdk